# Performance Monitor - IO Data Operations/sec

Tags: c#, performancecounter

I'm trying to get a value from the performance monitor [IO Data Operations/sec](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms804621.aspx) from a certain process and convert it into a readable value.

```
private static IEnumerable<String> GetProcessStatistics(String[] processList)
{
    Process[] process_List = Process.GetProcesses();

    foreach (string process in processList)
    {
        foreach (Process p in process_List)
        {
            if (process == p.ProcessName)
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                PerformanceCounter NETWORKperformanceCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "IO Data Operations/sec", p.ProcessName);

                NETWORKperformanceCounter.NextValue();
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

                double processNetworkdata = NETWORKperformanceCounter.RawValue;

                sb.AppendLine("ID: " + p.Id.ToString());
                sb.AppendLine("NAME: " + p.ProcessName);
                sb.AppendLine(String.Format("NETWORK USAGE: {0}", processNetworkdata));
                sb.AppendLine(String.Format("NETWORK USAGE: {0}", ConvertToReadableBandwidthSize(processNetworkdata)));

                yield return sb.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The first value returned is `4995043`
The second value returned is `4.76mbps`
The value showing in Task Manager is `48.5mbps`
I understand the values will never be `perfect` I thought I thought they would be very close since its using [RawValue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456044/why-wont-my-performance-counters-change)
Here is how its converting the `RawValue`

```
private static String ConvertToReadableBandwidthSize(Object size)
{
    string[] ordinals = new string[] { "","K","M", "G", "T", "P", "E" };
    long bandwidth = Convert.ToInt64(size);
    decimal rate = (decimal)bandwidth;
    int ordinal = 0;

    while (rate > 1024)
    {
        rate /= 1024;
        ordinal++;
    }

    return String.Format("{0} {1}bps", Math.Round(rate,2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero), ordinals[ordinal]);
 }
```

> Update
>   I have found with larger numbers, anything that should be in the `mbps` range eg `1.2mpbs`, I think its incorrect, however with smaller numbers or anything under the mbps range it seems to be ok